# htmltoolbar and htmlEditor separate background color

Tags: flutter, dart, html-editor

How can we get htmltoolbar and htmlEditor separate background color
My work
[image: current image]

Expectation:

[image: Expectation image]

```
htmlToolbarOptions: HtmlToolbarOptions(
        dropdownFocusColor: borderColor,
        dropdownBoxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
        buttonFillColor: yellowColor,
        renderBorder: true,
        toolbarType: ToolbarType.nativeExpandable,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(color:Color(0xff344054),),
        initiallyExpanded: false,
      ),
      htmlEditorOptions: HtmlEditorOptions(
        shouldEnsureVisible: true,
        initialText: data.taskStatus,
        hint: S.current.task_description,
        spellCheck: true,
        autoAdjustHeight: true,
        adjustHeightForKeyboard: false,
      ),
      otherOptions: const OtherOptions(height: 1500),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include your current code

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've attached the code